# How to call public function

Tags: vb.net

I have a public function to call default email client.

```
Public Function OpenEmail(ByVal EmailAddress As String, Optional ByVal Subject As String = "", Optional ByVal Body As String = "") As Boolean
    Dim bAns As Boolean = True
    Dim sParams As String
    sParams = EmailAddress
    If LCase(Strings.Left(sParams, 7)) <> "mailto:" Then _
        sParams = "mailto:" & sParams

    If Subject <> "" Then sParams = sParams & _
          "?subject=" & Subject

    If Body <> "" Then
        sParams = sParams & IIf(Subject = "", "?", "&")
        sParams = sParams & "body=" & Body
    End If
End Function
```

Then in Button_click, I put

```
 OpenEmail("mail@asdf.com", "Subject", Body:=" of my message")
```

But I am unable to call the function.  I want to open the client when I click button1
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this method (function) is defined in the `Test` class then create an instance of `Test`  and call it.

```
public class Test
Public Function OpenEmail(ByVal EmailAddress As String, Optional ByVal Subject As String = "", Optional ByVal Body As String = "") As Boolean
 ....
End Function
End Class
```

Code in button'c click handler:

```
Dim tst as New Test
tst.OpenEmail("mail@asdf.com", "Subject", Body:=" of my message")
```

PS: Use `System.Net.Mail` API to send email.

EDIT: To open default mail-client:

```
Process.Start("mailto:user@example.com?subject=Message Title&body=Message Content")
```

Comment: I just want button1 to open email client with my given email address

Comment: @FurqanSehgal - What mail-client you want to open? What type of application - webapp or winform?

Comment: winform, can't say anything about email client.  It could be anything on clinet's computer